# Como limpar uma variavel int em java?

Tags: java

Estou desenvolvendo um programinha que tem um menu que se eu digitar 1 cadastro um curso e se eu digitar 2 cadastro um aluno ambos os ifs estão funcionando tipo se eu digitar 1 cadastrar um curso fechar o console abrir de novo digitar 2 e cadstrar um aluno ocorre tudo normalmente mas se caso eu digitar 1 cadastrar o curso o menu reaparecer e eu digitar 2 para cadastrar um aluno msm eu digitando 2 ele entra de novo no if do curso segue o codigo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

tela.menu();

if (opc == 1){

for(posc=0;posc<10;posc++){

//seta o nome do curso
System.out.print("Digite o nome do curso: ");
nomecurso = entrada.next();
sala.setNome(nomecurso);
nomescurso[posc] = nomecurso;

//seta o codigo do curso
System.out.print("Digite o codigo do curso: ");
codigocurso = entrada.nextInt();
sala.setCodigo(codigocurso);
codigoscurso[posc] = codigocurso;

System.out.print("\\n");
posc++;
tela.menu();

}

}else if(opc == 2){

for(posa=0;posa<10;posa++){

//seta o nome do aluno 
System.out.print("Digite o nome do aluno: ");
nomealuno = entrada.next();
pessoa.setNome(nomealuno);
nomesaluno[posa] = nomealuno;

//seta a matricula do aluno 
System.out.print("Digite a matricula do aluno: ");
matricula = entrada.nextInt();
pessoa.setMatricula(matricula);
matriculas[posa] = matricula;

//seta o cpf do aluno 
System.out.print("Digite o cpf do aluno: ");
cpf = entrada.next();
pessoa.setCpf(cpf);
cpfs[posa] = cpf;

//liga um aluno a um curso 
System.out.print("Digite o codigo do curso cursado pelo aluno: ");
alunocursa = entrada.nextInt();
alunoscursam[posa] = alunocursa;    
}

System.out.print("\\n");
posa++;
tela.menu();
```

Comment: Onde está o metodo tela.menu()?

Comment: E este código está incompleto, algumas chaves não estão sendo fechadas.

Comment: Copiei e coloei só o main , mas vc entendeu meu problema ?

Answer (score 0):

Você quer limpar uma variável de número inteiro da memória?

Fazer isso diretamente não é possível... O java tem Garbage Collector, isso faz com que ele tire da memória sozinho quando a mesma já não é mais utilizada.

Você pode defini-la como -1 para identificar em qualquer lugar do código que ela está vazia caso seja necessário.

Comment: Já fiz isso ela continua com o primeiro valor que eu digitar sempre , tipo se eu entrar no if do 1 na primeira execução  e na segunda tentar entrar no if do 2 ele entra de novo no if de um e visse e versa, quero entrar em um if e zerala para na próxima execução entrar no if que quiser